Streamlit multipage app crashes on import pandas or import plotly.express statement
EDIT: Solution that worked for me
instead of using conda environment, I created environment using pip and it stopped crashing. Don't know what is the issue with conda based environment.
EDIT End
--
the code is more or less a copy paste of sample code given at link page_link
The way to run code will be streamlit run streamlit_app.py  
NOTE: The checked in version of the code works
Now if you go to file: pages/page2.py and uncomment line
# import pandas as pd
and run again the code crashes on running when you click on 'backtesting page' on the side bar
repository: https://github.com/alsm6169/streamlit-login
% python --version  
Python 3.11.9  
% streamlit version
Streamlit, version 1.35.0

minimum code

navigation.py

def authenticated_menu():
    # Show a navigation menu for authenticated users
    if st.session_state.get("logged_in", False):
        st.sidebar.page_link("pages/page1.py", label="Landing Page")
        st.sidebar.page_link("pages/page2.py", label="Backtesting Page")
        st.sidebar.page_link("streamlit_app.py", label="Login Page", disabled=True)


def unauthenticated_menu():
    # Show a navigation menu for unauthenticated users
    st.sidebar.page_link("streamlit_app.py", label="Login Page", disabled=False)


def menu():
    # Determine if a user is logged in or not, then show the correct
    # navigation menu
    if "logged_in" not in st.session_state or st.session_state.logged_in is None:
        unauthenticated_menu()
        return
    authenticated_menu()


app.py

import streamlit as st
import time
from navigation import menu

menu() # Render the dynamic menu!

username = st.text_input("Username")
password = st.text_input("Password", type="password")
login_button = st.button("Login", type="primary")

if login_button:
        if username == "test" and password == "test":
            st.success("Logged in as {}".format(username))
            st.session_state.logged_in = True
            st.switch_page("pages/page1.py")        


pages/page1.py

from navigation import menu
import streamlit as st

menu()
st.title('Landing Page (pages/page1.py)')


pages/page2.py

import streamlit as st
# import pandas as pd ###<--uncommenting leads to code crash
from navigation import menu
menu()
st.title('Backtesting Page (pages/page2.py)')


what do you mean by code crash? What error(s) are you getting?

--> zsh: segmentation fault  streamlit run streamlit_app.py and back to shell prompt

If you use conda list are all your held packages from the same channel? Did you install streamlit using pip or conda? Can you add complete reproduction steps?
